# ReactJS: How I do I use this this textInput component correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm super new to ReactJs. I'm finding the docs to be difficult to digest, as such I'm having trouble with something very basic. I'm trying to use this textinput component in my form and I don't know how to set value dynamically.

This is the TextInput component

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

import FormField from './FormField';

var TextInput = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    field: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  },
  render() {
    var {field, help, label, ...inputProps} = this.props
    return <FormField field={field} help={help} inputProps={inputProps} label={label}>
      <input
        {...inputProps}
        className="form-control"
        name={field.name}
        value={field.value}
        onBlur={field.onBlur}
        onChange={field.onChange}
      />
    </FormField>
  }
})

export default TextInput
```

This is where I'm using it

```
import React from 'react';
import ProfileSideBar from './ProfileSideBar';
import ProfileSectionLabel from './ProfileSectionLabel';
import TextInput from '../forms/TextInput';

class ProfileHome extends React.Component {

render() {

  return <div id='profile-wrapper'>
   <tr width='100%'>
    <td width="33%"> Location </td>
       <td width="33%"> 
         <TextInput field={location} 
          style={{height: 40,
                  borderColor: 'orange', 
                  borderWidth: 1}}>
         </TextInput>
       </td>
   </tr>
  </div>
```

Inside where I use TextInput, I'm trying to set a default value. So something like this:

location{
  value:'ny'
}
So if it exists, it'll populate ny, and if not it'll be blank.

I tried

```
<TextInput value={value}>
```

It just doesn't run. When I remove value = value the page renders but without the data I need of course.

I know I have to (or at least i think i know) Set the state or something and bind it to my profileHome component...I just don't know how.  If anyone can show me how to do this I would be so happy.  And if possible, throw in a good resource for me to look at.  I feel like angular was so much easier to pick up.

Comment: The ReactJS docs are honestly great. What isn't rendering? If ProfileHome isn't rendering, I'd try figuring that out first.

Comment: Profile home renders when I don't do value = value in textinput

Comment: Do you see 'ny' in the field? you should be doing <TextInput field={{value: 'ny'}} ... />.Then, you should see 'ny'. Granted, I don't think you'll be able to type anything into it because it sets value to 'ny', so it'll always be 'ny' unless you bind to onChange and reset the value to something else every time you type a letter.

Comment: I see. I'll try that when I get the chance. What's the correct syntax to use if I want to bind on change?

Comment: Usually, for an input you would do something like <input onChange={this.someFunction} />, but if you look at the library's source, you'll see that it explicitly binds the input's onChange to field.onChange, so what you do is you do something like <TextInput field={{value: 'ny', onChange: this.someFunction}} />. To be honest, this is a pretty odd way for a library to approach it, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `defaultValue`?

```
<TextInput defaultValue={value}>
```

This will render whatever is passed as a defaultValue, however you will still need to bind the `value` and `onChange` to reflect user interaction since you are using `<input>` as a controlled component. See React's [Controlled Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to go about it.

First, create the TextInput class and set your initial state of the text value in the constructor function and bind the correct 'this' context to the method you're going to create next:

```
class TextInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: 'ny' };
    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
  }
```

Then, create a method of the TextInput class that handles changes to the value of the input and sets the state accordingly:

```
onInputChange(event) {
  this.setState({ text: event.target.value });
}
```

Finally, in the render function, your input field would look like this (plus whatever other props you want to give it):

```
<input
  value={ this.state.text }
  onChange={ this.onInputChange }
/>
```

As for resources, the React documentation is pretty fantastic and I found Stephen Grider's course on udemy to be the best tutorial on React: https://www.udemy.com/react-redux/learn/#/.  Just be sure to understand the fundamentals of React (state and props) before moving on to the Redux part of the tutorial - where things get really fun, but definitely more complex.